# Error Returning Modified Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, return-value, pass-by-reference

Im fairly new to C Programming. I'm having a problem I still couldn't get rid of after literally hours of research. I'm going to paste my (essential) source code below in case you need an example. The problem is basically the following:

I have a method which returns 1 for success, 0 otherwise. It accepts an int-pointer which is being used as the function's actual return value, meaning that the passed pointer is modified by the method. I need to work with the modified value later. The behavior should be similar to the buffer pointer in a function like fgets or scanf. This works fine until I try to return the modified pointer value from the calling function. I receive an access violation error and the int value is the negative maximum, resp. undefined. How would I do that correctly?

I read about double pointers earlier but couldn't figure out how to incorporate this technique into my program... Are double pointers the correct approach?

Below my source code for reference :)

```
int validateInteger(int *out) {
    char buffer[17];
    fgets(buffer, 16, stdin);
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d")) {
        *out = atoi(buffer);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
int anotherFunction() {
    int selection = 0;

    while(1) {
        printf("Print something...");

        if (validateInteger(&selection) && selection >= 0 && selection <= 7) {
            break;
        } else {
            clearScreen();
        }
    }
    return selection;
}
```

```
int main() {

    while(1) {
        int sel = anotherFunction(); // THIS IS WHAT DOESN'T WORK!

        switch (sel) {
        case 0:
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Print some error msg here...");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: `if (sscanf(buffer, "%d")) {` what if this conditional isn't true?

Comment: If sscanf(buffer, "%d") isn't true, the function returns 0 and doesn't modify the int pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the following lines:

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%d")) {
    *out = atoi(buffer);
    return 1;
}
```

1. You don't need to use both `sscanf` and `atoi`. You need to use only one of them.
2. You forgot to pass `out` to `sscanf`. When the format string contains `%d`, the function looks for a pointer to an `int` to read the data into. Since you did not pass that argument, the program causes undefined behavior. In your case, it causes access violation error.

Use

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", out) == 1) {
   return 1;
}
```

You can also use the following instead of the previous lines.

```
*out = atoi(buffer);
return 1;
```

However, the only way to check for errors with this approach is to check whether the value of `*out` is `0`. If `0` is a legitimate value, then using the second approach is not good. Hence, I recommend the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) is wrong!! You never passed the address of the variable to store the scanned value. This invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As per the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2,

> [..] If there are insufficient arguments for the format,
>   the behavior is undefined.

You need to supply the variable to hold the scanned value, something like [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu) mentioned

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", out) == 1) {
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: sscanf() doesn't ask for user input. I use it only to make sure the input that is read by fgets() can be converted to integer. Is it still wrong? How would I do this right?

Comment: @armin Yes, it is wrong. You need to pass an output parameter and then, instead of using `atoi()`, you can directly use the value of that variable. :)